# Add column in DF if value modified of one column exists in DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to add one column in my dataframe (DF) according to another column value and whether that value is in my DF or not.

Example:

```
>>> d = { 'one' : pd.Series(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa-01', 'bb-02', 'dd']) }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
     one
0     aa
1     bb
2     cc
3  aa-01
4  bb-02
5     dd
```

I would like to add the following column if I can find another element with the current element appended -01 or -02. 
Example: in this dataframe only the elements 'aa' and 'bb' have the elements with the appended value, which are 'aa-01', and 'bb-02', thus only 'aa' and 'bb' will have the value `True` in the new column

Expected result:

```
>>> expected_df
     one  two
0     aa  True
1     bb  True
2     cc  False
3  aa-01  False
4  bb-02  False
5     dd  False
```

I believe I have to use `isin()` with `apply()`, but I can't figure out a way to modify the row and use `isin` at the same time within the function passed as argument to `apply`.

Comment: Is `df['two'] = ~df.one.str.contains('01|02')` what you are looking for?

Comment: No, that would return True for the row where one is 'cc'. I need to see if the dataframe has the current element with the appended value as well. It's not only a fact whether it has the appended number or not. I will edit my question to make it more clear. I can see why the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) to check for strings ending with the given chars and create a boolean mask. Followed by removing the last three chars after the mask generation fed to the [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method.

```
mask = df['one'].str.endswith(('-01','-02'))
df['two'] = df['one'].isin(df[mask].squeeze().str[:-3])
df
```

[image]

Comment: There are some elements which have the "-" (dash) in the row. I'm waiting the database to be repopulated to test something similar to what you made. I have to use some str manipulation as well

Comment: I presume my edited answer handles such cases too. Basically, it removes the last three chars and keeps the remaining untouched if they end with the mask mentioned.

Comment: It's awesome. It does exactly what I need. Thanks!